# Offset in reading columns in a textfile with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a text file containing an array of numbers from which I want to plot certain columns vs other columns. I defined a column function so I can assign a name to each column and then plot them, as in this sample code:

```
def column(matrix,i):
    return [float(row.split()[i]) for row in matrix]

Db = file('ResolutionEffects', 'r' )
HIcontour = column(Db,1)
Db.seek(1)
```

However when I display a column in my terminal to check that Python is indeed reading the right one, it appears that the first value of the column (as returned in my terminal) is actually the first value of the NEXT column in the text file. All the other numbers are from the correct column. There are no blank spaces or lines in the text file. As far as I can tell this offset happens to every column after the first one. 
If anyone can tell why this is happening, or find a more robust way to read columns in text files I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: To your last point ("a more robust way to read columns in text files"), I recommend numpy's [genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) or the slightly-less-general [loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

Comment: There's also the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module (which can handle any reasonable delimiter, not just commas), but the numpy functions seem more appropriate since you're dealing with numeric data.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I found loadtext to be a lot more robust. After converting my text file to a data file (.dat) I simply use this:

```
a=np.loadtxt('ResolutionEffects.dat', usecols=(0,1,11,12))
ax1.plot(a[:,0], a[:,1], 'dk', label='HI')
ax1.plot(a[:,2], a[:,3], 'dr', label='CO')
```

No weird offsets or bugs anymore :) Thanks Ajean and jedwards!